# What do I need to develop an Iron Python web app in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, ironpython

I've got Visual Studio 2010.  To develop a web app in Iron Python (i.e. to use a Ruby like language not C#) what downloads to I need?  e.g. is the DLR already in VS2010, Iron Python itself

Once setup would I actually be still developing an ASP.net MVC web app but just using Ruby for the language, or is the model something different to this?

thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to download

[**Python Extension for Visual Studio**](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/9ea113de-a009-46cd-99f5-65ef0595f937)

[**Python Tools for Visual Studio**](https://beta.visualstudio.com/vs/python/)

Then you can create an ironPython project. It's really easy.

and here are tools for ironPython

[**Python Tools**](http://ironpython.net/tools/)

Good Luck!

Comment: I highly recommend using the IronPython team's own extensions from http://www.ironpython.net/ironpython/tools/ instead.

Comment: You're right, I was going to add that link, instead I added the same link twice. As you can see, I wrote "tools for ironPython" and added extensions link..

Comment: (As usual) the posted link for iron python tools is out of date and non-functional. To download the tools, go to ironpython.net, pick the TOOLS menu item, then push DOWNLOAD button. Or something like that (should they reorg the site...)

Comment: @ArtSwri Good catch, thanks! Updated links. Link for extension was for VS 2010. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 2):

Out of the box, Visual Studio doesn't contain IronPython or IronRuby. You can add IronPython support using the tools from http://www.ironpython.net/ironpython/tools/; there is no equivalent for IronRuby yet.

Right now, there is no integration between IronPython and ASP.NET MVC. You can make it work, but it involves re-plumbing most of ASP.NET MVC. There is an IronRuby version available at http://github.com/jredville/ironrubymvc, but it's just a prototype (that said, it does work quite well).

Another option is to use an existing Python web framework (such as Django). However, every major Python web framework I've tried (and there's a lot of them) has had some issue with IronPython - those issues are getting rarer and rarer, but it also makes them much harder to track down. The low-hanging fruit for Python compatibility are long gone.

Rather than use a major framework, you could try to roll your own - there's a [great tutorial](http://pythonpaste.org/webob/do-it-yourself.html) that uses [WebOb](http://pythonpaste.org/webob/) to create a web framework, and WebOb works well on IronPython. Part of the reason that there are so many Python web frameworks is that it's so easy to make a simple one.

If you stick to the pure-Python route, you'll probably want to use [NWSGI](http://nwsgi.codeplex.com/) to deploy your app. [WSGI](http://wsgi.org/wsgi/) is the standard Python API for web apps, and NWSGI uses IronPython to implment the spec.

Finally, you can use the IronPython tools mentioned above to edit your code and use CPython to run it - you don't get debugger support, but most everything else should work just fine.

Also, IronRuby will run Rails just fine, but you don't get Visual Studio support.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to [hgulyan's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2842616/what-do-i-need-to-develop-an-iron-python-web-app-in-visual-studio-2010/2842645#2842645) above, **I would recommend everyone to [vote for Microsoft to integrate Python in VS2010](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/475830/ironpython-integration)**.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can only do it through an add-on

http://www.sapphiresteel.com/Ruby-In-Steel-Developer-Overview

Submit feedback here:

http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/479957/ironruby-integration-in-visual-studio-2010